# Error handling in Spring Cloud Stream Kafka in Batch mode

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I am using Spring Cloud Stream and Kafka Binder to consume messages in batches from a Kafka Topic. I am trying to implement an error handling mechanism. As per my understanding I can't use Spring Cloud Stream's `enableDLQ` property in batch mode.

I have found `RecoveringBatchErrorHandler` and `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer` to retry and send failure messages from the spring-kafka documentation. But I am not able to understand how to send the records to a custom DLQ topic following the functional programming standards. All the examples I can see is using KafkaTemplates.

Are there any good example where I can find the implementation?

This is the spring doc I have been referring to.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.5.12.RELEASE/reference/html/#recovering-batch-eh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That version is no longer supported as OSS https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka#support

With the current version, use the `DefaultErrorHandler` configured with a `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer` and throw a `BatchListenerExcecutionFailedException` to tell the framework which record in the batch failed.

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#annotation-error-handling and https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#dead-letters and https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#legacy-eh

Add a `ListenerContainerCustomizer` bean to add your configured error handler to the listener container.

Comment: Thanks @Gary Russell,
I have been able to implement a CustomErrorHandler by extending the DefaultErrorHandler and provide it to the ListnerContainerCustomizer.





Now, I have a different problem. I am calling a 3rd Party API with the batch of records to get more data, and if there is an error for one of the messages, the entire API call fails with the id of the failed record in the exception message. Now if I want to replay the entire batch without that record, what options do I have?

Comment: The framework can’t help with that. You would need to add such logic in your consumer method.