# Move only specific exception to DLQ in Spring Cloud Stream

Tags: amazon-sqs, spring-cloud-stream

I am using Spring Cloud Stream with AWS SQS. I've a use case where all exception except `CustomException` should move to **DLQ**. I am unable to find any reference for it. Can someone help here?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `ListenerContainerCustomizer` to configure a `DefaultErrorHandler` with a custom recoverer - one that delegates to a `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer` for just your custom exception.

See [Error handling in Spring Cloud Stream Kafka in Batch mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72880866/error-handling-in-spring-cloud-stream-kafka-in-batch-mode/72884456#72884456) for more information.